# Accesing the first element of an updated listview causes System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, xamarin, adapter

I update the list, removing from it unwanted items, and then I call adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged. When I **click upon the first element inside the updated ListView**, `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` pops up (*it seems that this element preserves the index it had inside the list before it has been updated*). When I click, instead, on other items inside the updated listview there are no problems.

```
List<Event> eventsToRemove = new List<Events>;

//Populating eventsToRemove with some "not-matching-some-criterion" <Event> instances taken from the original List<Event> events

for (var i = 0; i < eventsToRemove.Count; i++) {
                        events.Remove(eventsToRemove[i]);
}
adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

I guess the problem is with the thread that updates adapter and the thread that manages UI. I would like to resolve this issue:

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Parameter name: index
```

Log:

```
07-20 12:54:41.252 D/ViewRootImpl@3e1ee4d[Toast](18915): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
07-20 12:54:41.667 D/ViewRootImpl@3e1ee4d[Toast](18915): mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
07-20 12:54:41.667 D/ViewRootImpl@5f20f01[MainActivity](18915): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
07-20 12:54:41.668 D/ViewRootImpl@3e1ee4d[Toast](18915): dispatchDetachedFromWindow
07-20 12:54:41.674 D/InputTransport(18915): Input channel destroyed: fd=75
07-20 12:54:41.716 D/ViewRootImpl@5f20f01[MainActivity](18915): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
07-20 12:54:42.057 D/Mono    (18915): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0x73a4bea880] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0x738f4cf780]: 3
Unhandled Exception:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #10
Il thread 0xa è terminato con il codice 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #5
Il thread 0x5 è terminato con il codice 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #12
Il thread 0xc è terminato con il codice 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #6
Il thread 0x6 è terminato con il codice 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #11
Il thread 0xb è terminato con il codice 0 (0x0).
```

Github link with the respective code: https://github.com/eddybudge/PerugiaEventi1/blob/master/PerugiaEventi1/MainActivity.cs

Also, **when I click on the first element of the updated list**, I get the following output on the console:

```
[0:] Position: 0 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 1 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 2 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 3 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 4 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 5 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 6 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 7 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 8 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 9 Number of elements inside the list: 9
```

, while **when I click on any other button I get**

```
[0:] Position: x Number of elements inside the list: y
```

- it's strange, as only a single line should have been printed!!!

(I used `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Position: "+position+" Number of elements inside the list: "+eventi.Count());` every time a button is clicked)

**UPDATE:**

At the end I decided to **catch the exception** and to use inside catch **0 as index** - as during the test it was always the first element to cause the problem. **By the way I didn't get to the core of the problem** - that is what was causing it and why.

[image: Original list]

[image: Selecting a date]

[image: The updated list]

Comment: can you add the error log?

Comment: Added! Should be enough?

Comment: What is `events`? can you add the full related code?

Comment: I provided github link with code, is it ok? `events` is a `List<Event>` where `Event` is a **POJO**

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < eventsToRemove.Count; i++) {
                        events.Remove(eventsToRemove[i]);
}

are you removing all at a time in this for loop

Comment: at each iteration `i` I remove a single event `eventsToRemove[i]`

Answer (score 1):

For this question

> Also, when I click on the first element of the updated list, I get the
>   following output on the console

```
[0:] Position: 0 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 1 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 2 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 3 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 4 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 5 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 6 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 7 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 8 Number of elements inside the list: 9
[0:] Position: 9 Number of elements inside the list: 9
```

You just need to add the following code

```
 if (!bottoneEvento.HasOnClickListeners) {
 }
```

just as follows:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view = convertView ?? activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_item, parent, false);
        var bottoneEvento = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.bottoneEventAdapter);

        bottoneEvento.Text = eventi[position].Titolo;
        //bottoneEvento.Tag = position;  --forse non serve
        if (!bottoneEvento.HasOnClickListeners)  // key code
        {
            bottoneEvento.Click += (sender, args) =>
          {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Position: "+position+" Number of elements inside the list: "+eventi.Count());
            //bisogna, immagino fare l'update della view con notify - prima creando un observer.
            Intent dettagli = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(EventoInDettaglio));
            dettagli.PutExtra("titolo", bottoneEvento.Text);
            dettagli.PutExtra("url", eventi[position].Url);
            dettagli.PutExtra("inizia", eventi[position].Inizio);
            dettagli.PutExtra("finisce", eventi[position].Fine);
            dettagli.PutExtra("descrizione", eventi[position].Descrizione);
            Application.Context.StartActivity(dettagli);
          };
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Note: I  couldn't reproduce the first question as you said above.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but it seems that this idea does not work well, because, sometimes events' titles and their urls has been mismatched when I accessed them. I decided to try with exception handling, so it's a hardcoded solution based on empirical problem cases. I kinda patched the problem, but didn't get what causes it by the way...

Comment: When you added the judgement code(if (!bottoneEvento.HasOnClickListeners) {//...}), the second error still exists?But It works well in my test.

Comment: The second error does not exist, but another logical error pops up - it makes mismatched titles and other fields of the events. It can't be a solution for me.

Comment: Could you please post the details of your problem?

Comment: I mean what exactly was the error of ` it makes mismatched titles and other fields of the events` .

Comment: The button preserved the fields that actually had to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

you removing all items in single for loop..**Send position to remove event**

```
img_remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(eventsToRemove.size() > 0)
              events.Remove(eventsToRemove[position])
        }
    });
```

Comment: actually it is not true - I do not remove all items in a single iteration of the loop

Comment: to remove all items in a loop

Comment: pls put a log that print i value and size of arraylist at a time.. every time .. u will get clarity that the item position is there or not

Comment: Did as you asked me - added a line to the log with the index of the button and the size of the list,  each time when a button is clicked.

Comment: As for your code example, I do not eliminate buttons when I click on them - I eliminate buttons when the events they represent do not match some criteria - that is they do not occur on a date I pick with the DatePicker.